# Поиск столбцов, по фрагменту их названий

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, dataframe

Есть 7к признаков, многие среди которых - Id номер, соответственно их нужно удалить.
Написал код

```
to_drop=[]
for n in df_court.columns:
    index = n.find("id")
    if index ==-1:
        to_drop.append(n)

print(to_drop, len(to_drop))
```

но он выдает слишком много столбцов, в том числе таких, где фрагмент id не представлен.

```
   [.... 'r_data_courtPractice_dashboard_blocks_2_lastCaseLabel',
 'r_data_courtPractice_dashboard_blocks_2_selected', 
'r_data_courtPractice_dashboard_blocks_2_sum', 
'r_data_courtPractice_dashboard_blocks_2_title', 'r_data_courtPractice_title', 
'r_data_courtPractice_total'] 6708
```

Как исправить код, чтобы он правильно не ловил лишние имена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [DataFrame.filter(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) фильтрует DataFrame по названиям столбцов.

Пример:

```
In [370]: df
Out[370]:
   cookieDisclaimerAgree  data.id data.name  isFollowed        ...          showFollowReminder  showNps  showRequestDocsButton  showTaxRiskButton
0                   True      111     name1       False        ...                       False    False                  False              False
1                   True      112     name2       False        ...                       False    False                  False              False

[2 rows x 10 columns]

In [371]: df.columns
Out[371]:
Index(['cookieDisclaimerAgree', 'data.id', 'data.name', 'isFollowed', 'showErrorFeedbackButton', 'showFollowButton',
       'showFollowReminder', 'showNps', 'showRequestDocsButton', 'showTaxRiskButton'],
      dtype='object')

In [372]: df.filter(regex=r'^show')
Out[372]:
   showErrorFeedbackButton  showFollowButton  showFollowReminder  showNps  showRequestDocsButton  showTaxRiskButton
0                     True              True               False    False                  False              False
1                     True              True               False    False                  False              False

In [373]: df.filter(regex=r'^show.*Button$')
Out[373]:
   showErrorFeedbackButton  showFollowButton  showRequestDocsButton  showTaxRiskButton
0                     True              True                  False              False
1                     True              True                  False              False
```

Comment: Весь день меня спасаете!